# 2007 Dodge Charger 2.7L A/T - Limp Mode only on Heavy Throttle & Hanging in Gear

Tags: electrical, transmission, dodge, chrysler, dtc

Back with an update. Trying to help out my neighbor here.

2007 Charger with a 2.7L. 100k+ Miles on the body/transmission.

"If I drive very carefully I can get it up to highway speed. If I romp on it, or push it too hard to pass etc, seems to go into limp mode. Sometimes the speedo will follow the tach. Like it's hanging in gears."

Pulled Codes:

- P0344
- P0340

What do we think?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In case anyone is having this issue... We replaced the Camshaft Position Sensor with a new Mopar CMPS, and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cam codes, check the oil level if theres sludging its probably time for a new chain. I don’t remember if that engine has vvt or not.

The driver side cam sensor harness (theres only the one IIRC) runs right above the exhaust manifold. Check for brittle or stretched wires. Scope the sensor output and check the crank sensor output. Load test the wiring as well. Either can set those codes or a p0335.

If you have a scantool check the ckp/cmp variance pid it shouldn’t be higher than the single digits. If you replace either ckp or cmp sensor you need to reset the adaptives with a scantool.